# Why does using Angularjs ng-click, to call directives method($event) leads to Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I tried to write an custom map directive for an Phonegap + Angular OpenSource project you can find here: https://github.com/MariusSchmidt/Schreibwerkstatt/tree/Bettermap. My problem is, that when I try to use an event.stopPropagation() call within directive method mapClicked($event), called by ng-link, I get an 10 $digest() error in Internet Explorer most of the time. I would like to understand, what am I doing wrong?

The directive is angularmap:
https://github.com/MariusSchmidt/Schreibwerkstatt/blob/Bettermap/www/js/directives.js

The provided template is:

```
<div ng-style="containerStyle()" ng-click="mapClicked($event)">
    <div ng-style="mapStyle()">
        <img ng-repeat="icon in icons" ng-click="icon.toggleActive(); $event.stopPropagation();" ng-src="{{icon.getImage()}}" ng-style="iconStyle(icon)"  />
        <img src="./img/positionmarker.png" ng-style="positionMarkerStyle()" />
        <img ng-click="goToPosition()" src="img/position.png" style="">
        <a ng-href="#/poi" ><img src="img/info.png" style="float: right"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller is use it in is:

```
appControllers.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, Map) {
    $scope.userPosition = {latitude: 50.110290, longitude: 8.671265};
    console.log($scope);
});
```

It is used within a partial:

```
<main>
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="ym-wbox">
            <angularmap user-position="userPosition"></angularmap>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Hope you can help me out with that, I've been searching for days already

Best regards,

Marius

**Update**
Icons are defined in a JSON file:

```
"icons": [
        {
            "src": "./img/02-nikolaikirche1.png",
            "srcActive": "./img/02-nikolaikirche2.png",
            "top": 255,
            "left": 770,
            "coords": {
                "latitude": 50.110290,
                "longitude": 8.682265
            }
        },


        {
            "src": "./img/03-roemer1.png",
            "srcActive": "./img/03-roemer2.png",
            "top": 210,
            "left": 700,
            "coords": {
                "latitude": 50.110290,
                "longitude": 8.682265
            }
        }
]
```

The are mapped onto an icon property using:

```
this.icons = _.map(TOUR.icons, function (icon) {
        return {
            src: icon.src,
            srcActive: icon.srcActive,
            top: icon.top,
            left: icon.left,
            isActive: false,
            coords: icon.coords,
            getImage: function () {
                return this.isActive ? this.srcActive : this.src;
            },
            toggleActive: function() {
                this.isActive = !this.isActive
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: What does icons array look like?

Comment: Hi Bixi, Im pretty new to JavaScript and my JSFiddle usually dont work at all :-(:-(:-(.

Comment: I am not sure the syntax of the icons object is correct (not sure about the usage of `this`), but then I usually don't code that way. Why not using a factory or service to implement your icon object??

Comment: Hi Alex, we have set up unit tests for them so the work as expected. Should have been sth else. We solved the problem by redesigning the whole directive a bit. Result is available in git. I still don't know, what the problem exactely was.